# What is the difference between these PHP scripts?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm new on PHP and I am creating basics and simple projects to understand the language.
I'm trying to get information from a MySQL database, and I used this method:

```php
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "projects_colors");

if(mysqli_connect_error()){
    echo '<h1>Error:</h1>';
    die('There was an error while connecting to the database: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$stmt = 'SELECT * FROM colors';
$result = $con -> query($stmt);
$colors = $result -> fetch_array():

while($colors){
    echo '<p>ID: ' .colors['id']. '</p>';
    echo '<p>Name: ' .colors['name']. '</p>';
    echo '<p>Hexadecimal: ' .colors['hexadecimal']. '</p>'; 
}
```

And this other:

```php
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "projects_colors");

if(mysqli_connect_error()){
    echo '<h1>Error:</h1>';
    die('There was an error while connecting to the database: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$stmt = 'SELECT * FROM colors';
$result = $con -> query($stmt);

while($colors = $result -> fetch_array()){
    echo '<p>ID: ' .colors['id']. '</p>';
    echo '<p>Name: ' .colors['name']. '</p>';
    echo '<p>Hexadecimal: ' .colors['hexadecimal']. '</p>'; 
}
```

The first method doesn't work, but the second works fine. Why is this?

Comment: You can always use a foreach loop for example. It doesn't always have to be a while loop when dealing with queries.

Comment: How does this code run? In the `echo` lines you use `colors` not `$colors`.

Comment: `$colors = $result -> fetch_array():` is a typo so that is one issue. When you call the fetch that returns 1 result. You need to iterate the `fetch` to get back multiple rows.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files as well as patterns to use when writing code like this.

Answer (score 2):

Look at it this way: Unless you have something that changes `$colors` then that loop will never terminate. The first example is just flat-out wrong, it can never work as intended, it will just `echo` forever.

The second keeps running until it runs out of rows to fetch. You can see examples of that style [in the PHP documentation for `fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array).

Answer (score 2):

The while is entering an infinite loop in the first. You are checking the value of $colors which is not changing at any part of the loop, and thus forever true or not entering the loop if false.

I am not sure, but in the second, $result->fetch_array() is probably updating a pointer inside $result which happens to return false once all the results have been fetched.

Comment: `fetch_array` returns the next row in the result set or `NULL` if no further rows are present.